# Adding Trial column, grouped by subject with an index

Tags: r

Fairly new to R here and  hoping for some help.

I need to add a column indicating Trial number at a row indexed by 'MovieStart' repeated until 'MovieEnd', grouped by the ParticipantID.

[Desired output in red - TRIAL column][1]

My current data frame looks like this:

```
 Participant ID    StudioEvent    
 1                 
 1                 MovieStart
 1
 1
 1                 MovieEnd
 1
 1                 MovieStart
 1
 1
 1                 MovieEnd
 2
 2
 2                 MovieStart
 2
 2
 2
 2                 MovieEnd
 2
 2                 MovieStart
 2
 2
 2                 MovieEnd
```

This is what I hope for:

```
 Participant ID    StudioEvent   Trial   
 1                 
 1                 MovieStart    1 
 1                               1
 1                               1
 1                 MovieEnd      1
 1
 1                 MovieStart    2 
 1                               2
 1                               2
 1                 MovieEnd      2
 2
 2
 2                 MovieStart    1
 2                               1
 2                               1
 2                               1
 2                 MovieEnd      1
 2
 2                 MovieStart    2
 2                               2
 2                               2
 2                 MovieEnd      2
```

so far, I have tried:

```
       library(dplyr)
    
    new_df <- trial_df %>%
      group_by(ParticipantName) %>%
      mutate(trial_number = row_number())
    
    data$Trial   <- numeric(17)
    movie_started <- FALSE
    
    for(i in 1:nrow(data))
    {
      if(movie_started) data$Trial[i] <- data$Trial[i = 1] 
      if(data$StudioEvent[i] == "MovieStart") movie_started <- TRUE
      if(data$StudioEvent[i] == "MovieEnd")   movie_started <- FALSE
    }
    
    data$Trial <- as.character(data$Trial)
    data$Trial[data$Trial == "1" & data$StudioEvent != "MovieStart"] <- ""
    
    data$Trial <- as.numeric(data$Trial)
```

...but it doesn't do what I want. Any ideas what I could change?
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks, hope this is better

Answer (score 0):

For each `ParticipantID` you can increment `Trial` using `cumsum` when `"MovieStart"` value is detected in `StudioEvent`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ParticipantID) %>%
  mutate(Trial = cumsum(StudioEvent == 'MovieStart'))
```

Comment: ....seriously?! That's it? hahah ! I sure feel dumb. Thank you Ronak.